# proving $\frac{1}{n}$ maximises entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

With $n$ being the cardinality of $X$. We can use Jensen's inequality to show that the maximum of the entropy function as such:
$$
\begin{align}
H(X) &= -\sum_{i=1}^np_i log(p_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^np_i log(\frac{1}{p_i}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[log(x)] \\
&\leq log(\mathbb{E}[x]) \\
&\leq log \sum_{i=1}^np_i \frac{1}{p_i} \\
&\leq log(n)
\end{align}
$$

How do we prove that $p_i = \frac{1}{n}$ achieves the maximum ?

More generally how would one go about proving things when there are series involved ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, why not just compute the sum and show, that it hits the upper bound?:
$$
\sum{p_i}\log{\frac{1}{p_i}}
= \frac{\sum{\log{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}}}}{n}
= \frac{n\cdot \log{n}}{n}
=\log{n}
$$
I don't think, there is a general answer to your second question. Sometimes you compute the sum, sometimes you show boundary conditions, etc. Depends on the specific question, preconditions, involved expressions, etc.

Comment: what if you didn't know the solution to start with ?

Comment: Ah, then, in this case, use the method of Lagrange multipliers with $\sum{p_i} = 1$ as a condition.